# Como alterar a cor do botão do formulario com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código `JavaScript`, como procedo para conseguir alterar a cor do background do botão quando o mesmo estiver desabilitado?

```js
let campoSenha = document.querySelector('input[name="senha_imob"]');
let campoConfirmarSenha = document.querySelector('input[name="rsenha_imob"]');
let botao = document.querySelector('input[name="btn-entrar"]');
    
campoSenha.addEventListener('input', function(){
    verificaCampos();
});
    
campoConfirmarSenha.addEventListener('input', function(){
    verificaCampos();
});
    
function verificaCampos() {
    if(campoSenha.value == campoConfirmarSenha.value && campoSenha.value.length > 8)
     botao.disabled = false;
    else
     botao.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
.frm-botao {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#EA8419;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.frm-botao:hover {
    background-color:#C16911;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="btn-entrar" value="ATUALIZAR" class="frm-botao" disabled />
```

Comment: Não seria mias interessante mudar quando estiver habilitado. Tipo verde?

Comment: @LeAndrade Muito interesante, tipo cinza escuro quando desabilitado e verde quando habilitado. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode simplesmente adicionar uma nova classe no css onde o botão é cinza e adicionar ou remover a classe do botão conforme ele fica ativo/inativo, não?

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar somente `css` para isso, com a pseudo-class `:disabled`:

```css
button:disabled {
  background-color: cyan
}
```

```html
<p>
<button>
Sou um botão sem disabled
</button>
</p>
<p>
<button disabled>
  Sou um botão desabilitado
</button>
</p>
```

Ou se quiser usar somente `javascript`, pode fazer assim:

```
botao.style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
```

```js
document.getElementById('b2').onclick = function() {
   var botao = document.getElementById('b1');
   botao.disabled = true;
   botao.style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
}
```

```html
 <p>
    <button id='b1'>
      Botão
    </button>
    </p>
    <p>
    <button id='b2'>
      Desabilitar botão
    </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Não funcionou!!

Comment: qual não funcionou, o `css` ou a linha em `javascript`?

Comment: coloquei o código javascript na pergunta e funciona, dê uma olhada

Answer (score 0):

Cara fiz um exemplo, mas vale algumas considerações:

- Se vc colocou estilo no botão, então não faz muito sentido o disabled, sugiro deixar ao invés de laranja uma cor mais pesada e sem **hover** no botão, pois dá a entender que está habilitado e não desabilitado.
- Retirei os **addEventListener()**, acho que no caso não precisa, pois estava escutando os valores dos dois `input`. Deixei a função que valida os campos no evento **onkeyup** no último input, fazendo mais sentido.

```js
let campoSenha = document.querySelector('input[name="senha_imob"]');
let campoConfirmarSenha = document.querySelector('input[name="rsenha_imob"]');
let botao = document.querySelector('input[name="btn-entrar"]');
    
function verificaCampos() {
    if(campoSenha.value == campoConfirmarSenha.value && campoConfirmarSenha.value.length < 8 ){
      botao.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      botao.disabled = false;
    }else{
      botao.style.backgroundColor = '#EA8419';
      botao.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```css
.frm-botao {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#EA8419;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.frm-botao:hover {
    background-color:#C16911;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" name="senha_imob">
<input type="password" name="rsenha_imob" onkeyup="verificaCampos()">
<input type="submit" name="btn-entrar" value="ATUALIZAR" class="frm-botao" disabled>
```

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui mesmo em executar e a cor não foi alterada.

Comment: Vc tem que digitar senhas iguais menores que 8 digitos e **tirar o foco (sair de dentro do input, clicar fora do input)** para trocar de cor.

Comment: Editei a resposta para vc entender melhor. Troquei o **onblur** por **keyup**.

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma:

Javascript:

```
function verificaCampos() {
if(campoSenha.value == campoConfirmarSenha.value && campoSenha.value.length > 8)
    botao.disabled = false;
    botao.classList.remove('frm-botao-disabled');
    botao.classList.add('frm-botao');
else
    botao.disabled = true;
    botao.classList.remove('frm-botao');
    botao.classList.add('frm-botao-disabled');
}
```

Css:

```
.frm-botao {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#EA8419;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.frm-botao:hover {
    background-color:#C16911;
}
.frm-botao-disabled {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#A9A9A9;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn-entrar" value="ATUALIZAR" class="frm-botao" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

Para as pessoas que estão tendo problema com essa parte de trocar a cor ou desabilitar um botão até que certos campos estejam preenchidos ou iguais, fica aqui um código bem simples que supre exatamente esse problema.

#### HTML 5

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
   <script src="js.js"></script>
   <title>Sandbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
    <input type="password" name="input-password" class="frm-input" id="frm-input" onchange="func()" />
    <input type="password" name="input-confirm" class="frm-input" id="frm-input-confirm" onchange="func()" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn-entrar" value="ATUALIZAR" class="frm-botao disabled" id="btn-entrar" />
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

#### CSS 3

```
.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.frm-input {
 width: 10vw;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.frm-botao {
 width: 10vw;
 background-color: #ea8419;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.frm-botao:hover {
 background-color: #c16911;
}

.disabled {
 pointer-events: none;
 filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
function func() {
 let passwordInput = document.getElementById("frm-input");
 let passwordInputConfirm = document.getElementById("frm-input-confirm");
 let botao = document.getElementById("btn-entrar");

 if (passwordInput.value == passwordInputConfirm.value && passwordInput.value.length >= 8) {
  botao.classList.remove("disabled");
 } else {
  botao.classList.add("disabled");
 }
}
```

Utilizando esses 3 códigos é possível criar validações mais complexas, portanto utilize e aprimore da melhor forma para o seu caso.

Não usei Regex nem jQuery.